# Which RX card for ETH mining?

Tags: mining, bitcoin, gpu

i've seen that mining is getting more popular and i thought that i maybe should jump onto the train. So i've already got a 550W power supply from an older build, i can get a Asus P7P550 PRO motherboard and an i5 760 both used for around 100$ and i'm gonna build the case myself. So first question: Do you have any ideas for a better build for ethereum mining? And second question: Which RX gpu is best with the build and for ethereum mining? I'm able to get a RX 470, RX 480, RX 570 and RX 580 all both 4GB and 8GB. But also which BRAND do you suggest would be best for the mining because i've head that the sapphire RX 470 reference design is the best but that's pretty much the only card that's sold out where i live. Is it even worth it mining with one gpu only? And for the last question: Do you think a 14 year old who only have build a gamer rig could be able to build a miner rig like this?

So thanks and have a nice day ;)

EDIT: I also wanna know which gpu uses least electricity because it's quite expensive where i live

Answer (score 1):

You could probably make a mining rig cause I am also a 13 year old who had only built a gaming rig who made a mining rig, most of those cards would probably be profitable and I don't think there is much of a difference in the brands. I am making off my 2 cards, 6 dollars a day minus 1 for electricity at a .11$/KW so it would take you electricity cost being like .5 for it to not be profitable. The other parts of the build should be fine. and the 470 4gb probably uses the least electricity but you probably won't need to worry about electricity that much.